# How to fix Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis (Redis::TimeoutError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq with Redis. I have got Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis (Redis::TimeoutError).

As I search this issue on google. I found the suggestion like set network_timeout value. the default is 5. So my question is what is the maximum value for a network_timeout parameter of Redis?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: did you start the sidekiq server??? from application root command `bundle exec sidekiq`

Comment: Abhishek thanks for the reply. Yes, I started sidekiq server.

Comment: did u add `sidekiq.yml` ??

Comment: Yes sidekiq.yml is there.

Comment: does `telnet $REDIS_IP $REDIS_PORT`  gives you a statement like `Connected to $REDIS_IP`, to be sure it's otherwise reachable

Comment: Actually, this error does not occur all time. Sometimes it occurs So if try this command now then this is connected but I need to check when this error occurs.